# Identifying a bone I found in Central France

Tags: species-identification, bone-biology, bone

I found this bone in Auvergne as a child. This specific area is apparently well-known to paleontologists and I found the bone in a field very close to scientific excavations (literally meters away from the area that was delimited by ropes). I picked it up and brought it to a local museum but back then they simply told me something like "lucky find, it might be a prehistoric animal! You can keep it, we only do mammoths here."

Years passed and I've kept this bone (probably a vertebra, coccyx or sacrum) on a shelf. Now, my curiosity is having the best of me and I would really like to identify it.

I spent some time looking at "bone identification" forums, databases and charts online, but they were quite disappointing. However, I am almost sure the bone belongs to the spine of a mammal.

Here are pictures (mug for scale):

[image: Bone picture 1]
[image: Bone picture 2]

Comment: Definitely spine, pretty certain on sacrum too, which most likely makes it mammalian (given location...), but have no idea on species. Might not be identifiable as lots of it is missing.